# Javascript pass geolocation as string variable

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I want to tag camera photos with geolocation (coordinates are fine).
Here's a piece of my code:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);

    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
     return position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

and inside the method takePhoto() I have:

```
...

    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    var loc = getLocation();
    context.strokeText(loc, 10, 50);

...
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass a variable that holds the location coordinates, I've tried many things but without success. Anybody any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: I would like it to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: what you expect, can show example?

Comment: I added an edit with picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need async await for resolve this issue

```js
function takePhoto(position) {
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function getLocation() {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                return resolve(position);
            }, function(err) {
                return reject(err);
            });

        } else {
            return reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    })


}

(async function() {

    const coords = await getLocation();

    takePhoto(coords);


})().then(() => {
    console.log("done")
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
})
```

```html
<div id="x">empty</div>
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't help cause I want to pass this variable to the method takePhoto() and put the coordinates ON the photo...

Comment: i've change code and now you can pass variable to the method